# Disable buttons to avoid multiple form submission

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I have a web form and I have noticed that it generates multiple submissions of the same data (spaced about 100 milliseconds). Based on my research, disabling buttons after form submission is one of a few things to do. I have the following two methods to disable form buttons:

```
Method 1:
$('form#my-form').submit(function(e) {
    $(this).find('button').prop("disabled",true);
    return true;
});

Method 2:
$('form#my-form').submit(function(e) {
    $(this).find('button').attr('onclick',"return false;");
});
```

Let's just focus on disabling buttons at form submission in the browser. Which method is better?  Or other better ways? Any implications? I know that Method 1 is unable to pass to the backend the information of which button being clicked if a form has multiple buttons for different things.

Comment: you can use $("form").submit(function(){e.preventDefaults()}); after your first submission

Comment: I think this is opinion-based or belongs to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as it's not a problem and can be done in many ways.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Could you please show it in code? I tried that before, but didn't like the code ("after your first submission") in terms of clean code.

Comment: If you set the button type propertie to `type="button"` it won't trigger the form. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/932653/9119186) might be helpfull

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Prevent Users from Submitting a Form Twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814157/how-to-prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-twice) (second answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use that method: 
[event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$('form#my-form').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault() 
     //do somethings
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Doesn't this stop any form submission?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try ,I think delay can make your work easy.

```
 $('#id').on('click',function(){
    // let a common class(disable-btn) for each button which should be disabled for on second
    $('.disable-btn').prop('disabled',true);
    setTimeout(function(){
       // enable click after 1 second
       $('.disable-btn').prop('disabled',false);
    },1000); // 1 second delay
});
```